# ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH for preflight request in chrome only first time

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, request, preflight, proxy-authentication

While hitting AWS gateway API's, there is getting ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH error with status:0 on preflight (OPTIONS)request.
This error is on first time only and when it tries for the second time its working fine as expected.
Any comments on the same.

API is hitting from Angular application.

What I should try to resolve this issue?
Is there any changes needs to be done from frontend side?
Is this backend related issue?